# Database context of unexpected poor performance to simple update query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-update, amazon-rds

I have a use case to update a column in table1 based on the presence of a value of an id in table2. I can execute a `SELECT` statement in a fraction of a second, but the update query takes unreasonably long (~30+ minutes)

Here is the `SELECT` statement:

```sql
-- 0.02 seconds
SELECT id FROM table_1
WHERE table_1.other_id = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT col_1
    FROM table_2
    WHERE table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id)
```

Here is the `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
-- 30 minutes and counting
UPDATE table_1
SET isactive = TRUE
WHERE table_1.other_id = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT col_1
    FROM table_2
    WHERE table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id)
```

there are `btree` indices on `table_1.id`, `table_1.other_id`, and `table_2.table_1_id`. All the id's mentioned here are integers. No index in boolean `table_1.isactive`. `table_1` is ~16K records. `table_2` is ~120M records.

Any help would be very welcome.

I've run `EXPLAIN` but can't make sense of the results thus far. The execution plan for the select is virtually identical to the execution plan for the update. Still waiting for the query to finish to get the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: Please get the execution plan (JSON) and post it in [checktheplan](https://checktheplan.com/?engine=postgresql).

Comment: For that number of rows the query should be pretty much instantaneous, unless your RDS has extremely limited resources.

Comment: Yeah, so issue wasn't with the Query. As The Impaler points out, the query was running basically instantaneously.  The issue was a prior query that was locking the table, even after that prior process was inactive and it's transaction was committed.  Maybe someone here has some insight into why such locks can persist? `pg_terminate_backend(<pid>)` solved the issue, though pg_cancel_backend(<pid>)` did not.  cleaned up some code surrounding the query to ensure the prior code block did not have an open connection and now things are performing as expected, in a matter of microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, this query should never have been so slow. it was simply a matter of a blocked transaction. I should've paid closer attention to the query status: `Lock:transactionid` in AWS performance insights, and checked for blocked queries in the db itself. It turned out to be a matter of ensuring prior connections were closed.